# FAILED: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I am running two apache-beam pipelines on the local Flink 1.14 cluster, which raises `Could not acquire the minimum required resources.` error always a while after it processes all messages from kafka topic, regardless I send there 1000 or 100K messages it's always after there's nothing to read. Also, I noticed that CPU usage of my mac increases heavily after there's nothing to read from kafka topics.

I tripled jobmanager and taskmanager memory, reduced parallelism, and changed heap size, but none of the helped.

This is my flink-conf.yaml:

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: localhost
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123

jobmanager.memory.process.size: 4800m
taskmanager.memory.process.size: 5184m
taskmanager.memory.managed.size: 0

taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
parallelism.default: 2

jobmanager.execution.failover-strategy: region
restart-strategy: failure-rate
```

Flink-standalonesession.local.log

```
2023-01-24 11:28:33,111 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - [3]Read topic - 1/{KafkaIO.Read, Remove Kafka Metadata} -> [10]{Deserialize without magic byte, Contact Look-up , Add prefix, User look-up, Lead look-up, Product Usage User look-up, Deletion look-up, Apply final where condition, Apply final transformation, Dic2String - Leading topic} -> [2]Write to CONTACTS_OUT topic/{Kafka ProducerRecord, KafkaIO.WriteRecords} (1/1) (7b82955914db7b35635f0c7a0e3793d6) switched from RUNNING to FAILED on 127.0.0.1:53351-0e899a @ localhost (dataPort=53353).
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Heartbeat of TaskManager with id 127.0.0.1:53351-0e899a timed out.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster$TaskManagerHeartbeatListener.notifyHeartbeatTimeout(JobMaster.java:1343) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.heartbeat.HeartbeatMonitorImpl.run(HeartbeatMonitorImpl.java:155) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRunAsync$4(AkkaRpcActor.java:455) ~[flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68) ~[flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:455) ~[flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:213) ~[flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:78) ~[flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163) ~[flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) [?:?]

.
.
.

2023-01-24 11:28:36,807 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Source: Impulse -> [3]Read topic - Lead/KafkaIO.Read/KafkaIO.Read.ReadFromKafkaViaUnbounded/Read(KafkaUnboundedSource)/{ParDo(OutputSingleSource), ParDo(UnboundedSourceAsSDFWrapper)} (1/1) (fa81660c9e8094977d150182626af918) switched from SCHEDULED to FAILED on [unassigned resource].
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.
2023-01-24 11:28:36,808 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Source: Impulse -> [3]Read topic - 1/KafkaIO.Read/KafkaIO.Read.ReadFromKafkaViaUnbounded/Read(KafkaUnboundedSource)/{ParDo(OutputSingleSource), ParDo(UnboundedSourceAsSDFWrapper)} (1/1) (22d6e55a565dd19086e372c058a65b72) switched from SCHEDULED to FAILED on [unassigned resource].
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.
2023-01-24 11:28:36,810 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Discarding the results produced by task execution 22d6e55a565dd19086e372c058a65b72.
2023-01-24 11:28:36,811 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Discarding the results produced by task execution fa81660c9e8094977d150182626af918.
2023-01-24 11:28:36,812 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.RestartPipelinedRegionFailoverStrategy [] - Calculating tasks to restart to recover the failed task cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0.
2023-01-24 11:28:36,813 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.RestartPipelinedRegionFailoverStrategy [] - 2 tasks should be restarted to recover the failed task cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0. 
2023-01-24 11:28:36,814 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.RestartPipelinedRegionFailoverStrategy [] - Calculating tasks to restart to recover the failed task cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0.
2023-01-24 11:28:36,814 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.RestartPipelinedRegionFailoverStrategy [] - 2 tasks should be restarted to recover the failed task cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0. 
2023-01-24 11:28:36,816 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Job update-contact (71870fb09db1c5d57046edd8d020971b) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING.
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by FailureRateRestartBackoffTimeStrategy(FailureRateRestartBackoffTimeStrategy(failuresIntervalMS=60000,backoffTimeMS=1000,maxFailuresPerInterval=1)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:138) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:82) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:228) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:218) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:209) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:679) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.UpdateSchedulerNgOnInternalFailuresListener.notifyTaskFailure(UpdateSchedulerNgOnInternalFailuresListener.java:51) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraph.notifySchedulerNgAboutInternalTaskFailure(DefaultExecutionGraph.java:1473) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.processFail(Execution.java:1133) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.processFail(Execution.java:1073) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.markFailed(Execution.java:912) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionVertex.markFailed(ExecutionVertex.java:474) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionVertexOperations.markFailed(DefaultExecutionVertexOperations.java:41) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskDeploymentFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:562) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.lambda$assignAllResourcesAndRegisterProducedPartitions$6(DefaultScheduler.java:457) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:907) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge$PendingRequest.failRequest(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:545) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.cancelPendingRequests(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:127) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.failPendingRequests(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:355) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.notifyNotEnoughResourcesAvailable(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:344) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.notifyNotEnoughResourcesAvailable(JobMaster.java:809) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$0(AkkaRpcActor.java:308) ~[flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83) ~[flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:307) ~[flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:217) ~[flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:78) ~[flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163) ~[flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243) [flink-rpc-akka_1130a6a2-bae5-4fe6-a274-c23dbe38ebac.jar:1.14.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) [?:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.lambda$assignResource$8(DefaultScheduler.java:515) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:632) ~[?:?]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.
```

flink-taskexecurtor.local.log

```
2023-01-24 11:27:51,604 WARN  org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ExecutionStateSampler     [] - Operation ongoing in bundle 2672 for at least 09m21s without outputting or completing:
  at java.base@11.0.16/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
  at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
  at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.CancellableQueue.take(CancellableQueue.java:94)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.awaitCompletion(BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.java:122)
  at app//org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:546)
  at app//org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnHarness$$Lambda$170/0x00000008402b8040.apply(Unknown Source)
  at app//org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:151)
  at app//org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:116)
  at app//org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver$$Lambda$177/0x00000008402bbc40.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
  at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:162)
  at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
  at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) 
2023-01-24 11:29:53,564 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState [] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-Reader-0_offset_consumer_1403650759_none-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1403650759_none] Resetting offset for partition D_CONTACT-0 to offset 10007.
2023-01-24 11:29:57,167 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.util.ClusterUncaughtExceptionHandler [] - WARNING: Thread 'grpc-nio-worker-ELG-3-4' produced an uncaught exception. If you want to fail on uncaught exceptions, then configure cluster.uncaught-exception-handling accordingly
2023-01-24 11:29:57,176 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.util.ClusterUncaughtExceptionHandler [] - WARNING: Thread 'grpc-nio-worker-ELG-3-3' produced an uncaught exception. If you want to fail on uncaught exceptions, then configure cluster.uncaught-exception-handling accordingly
2023-01-24 11:29:34,305 WARN  org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector       [] - Unexpected exception in the selector loop.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2023-01-24 11:29:34,306 ERROR org.apache.flink.util.FatalExitExceptionHandler              [] - FATAL: Thread 'flink-7' produced an uncaught exception. Stopping the process...
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2023-01-24 11:29:49,956 ERROR org.apache.flink.util.FatalExitExceptionHandler              [] - FATAL: Thread 'flink-scheduler-1' produced an uncaught exception. Stopping the process...
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2023-01-24 11:29:34,306 ERROR org.apache.flink.util.FatalExitExceptionHandler              [] - FATAL: Thread 'flink-metrics-12' produced an uncaught exception. Stopping the process...
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2023-01-24 11:29:49,958 ERROR org.apache.flink.util.FatalExitExceptionHandler              [] - FATAL: Thread 'Time Trigger for [3]Read topic - Lead/{KafkaIO.Read, Remove Kafka Metadata} -> [3]{Deserialize - Contact, Update Contact state stores, Dic2String - c topic} -> [2]Write to c topic/{Kafka ProducerRecord, KafkaIO.WriteRecords} (1/1)#0' produced an uncaught exception. Stopping the process...
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2023-01-24 11:30:03,789 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.PermanentBlobCache             [] - Shutting down BLOB cache
2023-01-24 11:30:06,226 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.TransientBlobCache             [] - Shutting down BLOB cache
2023-01-24 11:30:10,098 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.TaskExecutorStateChangelogStoragesManager [] - Shutting down TaskExecutorStateChangelogStoragesManager.
2023-01-24 11:30:10,098 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.TaskExecutorLocalStateStoresManager [] - Shutting down TaskExecutorLocalStateStoresManager.
```

Comment: The issue seems to be caused by Flink's default state store. Updating config with `state.backend: rocksdb` solved it.